# In a Batch file, How do I get files with the largest number in the names?

Tags: java, cmd, filenames

I need to do this in Command prompt windows Batch file.  I have a batch file and I need to compare the file name of 2 files; e.g. I have `whatever-5428.jar` and `whatever-9001.jar` and possibly more `whatever*.jar` files.

I need to make a script for my batch file so it uses the jar with the highest number. (the 9001 is higher than 5428). It makes it more difficult for me as I cannot do `java -jar -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m whatever*.jar` as java doesn't like wildcards.

I need to use it with the java script above as i am launching it with a certain amount of RAM and Perm Size.

In a batch file, how can I get the jar file with the biggest number in it? I am not sure on how to use java at all, i am just launching it from a batch file and perhaps there could be some way to use something to check the file with the highest number then launch that file with this command line: `java -jar -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m MYFILENAMEWITHTHEHIGHESTNUMBERATTHEEND.jar`

See my batch file here: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/XyvIN2VpgF/

Comment: @Eric Leschinski I mean the one with the biggest number on the end

Comment: You can alternatively use a small java script to decide which jar to load and do the final launch from within the java script, but I'm curious why you wouldn't know which jar to use ahead of time. Maven is great for keeping track of jar dependencies

Comment: @kdubb I am dealing with some jar files and it will auto update them off some website (which name their filenames by version e.g. 4005, 8119). I will then need to determine the filename with the highest number so i can make my batch file delete the rest and run the one with the highest number.

I saw the thing with the FindStr but if i possibly have multiple files i'm not sure its compatible and as already mentioned, it is very limited.

I want it to be purely in batch so it doesn't require any external files, just the .bat itself.

Comment: Is it possible to have the auto-updater remove the old file when the new one is downloaded? Seems like something you don't want to worry about later then and will be easier to create a batch file if there are not multiple versions of the same jar.

Comment: @kdubb I understand what you mean however it will check for an update before downloading however if there isnt an update available, it won't update.

Comment: Ideally you'd place the delete in the logic only after a successful update

Comment: @kdubb Yes, it would delete the rest of the "whatever*.jar" files after an successful update. Any solution?

Comment: you can either have your batch file kickoff a small java script to delete the older one or place the delete logic in the update script. I'd suggest opening a new thread for the update script if you want that edited

Comment: When it comes to java, i have no clue on how to use it apart from that one command line for java.exe above. I can make the update script easily (on agreement with the website owner) and can delete the previous versions using the script however i need to know how CMD can get the filename with the highest number and run that with that one command line but i dont know how

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Java Regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to parse out the numbers to compare between the two files. Regex is very flexible and will be able to handle the wildcards

Edit:
See the below example with output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(getTrailingNumber("whatever-5428.jar"));
    System.out.println(getTrailingNumber("whatever-9001.jar"));
}

public static String getTrailingNumber(String filename)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-(\\d+)\\.");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);
    matcher.find();

    return matcher.group(1);
}
```

Ouput:

> 5428
>   9001

Comment: I don't get regex, could you offer an example? It all has to stay in a batch file though

Answer (score 0):

Using DOS in a windows batch file to do string matching and regular expressions a really ugly hack.  It's like trying to use a power saw to bang in a nail. You *can* do it, but should you?  No.

The dos command `findstr` can do a limited amount of matching and regular expressions as in this example:

```
@Echo Off
CD "C:\workspace"
Dir /B>Dir.temp
FindStr /R "[0-9]" "Dir.temp">FindStr.temp
Del Dir.temp
For /F "tokens=*" %%a In (FindStr.temp) Do Call :WorkIt "%%a"
Del FindStr.temp
Exit /B

:WorkIt
:: Insert code here.  Use %1 to get the file name with quotes.  For example:
Echo Found a number in %1
Exit /B
```

1. Make a directory called C:\workspace.
2. Make a file called mybat.bat and put the above code in there.
3. Put two files in C:\workspace called `1234.txt` and `abcd.txt`
4. Run the above bat file.
5. The output is as follows:

> C:\workspace>mybatch.bat
>
> Found a number in "1234.txt"

The DOS `FindStr` command only returned files/folders with the numbers 0 through 9 in them.  It omitted the `abcd.txt` and included the `1234.txt`.  You could increase the complexity of the regular expression to parse out only the numbers, then convert them to integers, then return the one with the biggest number.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]') do (
  set "filename=%%a"
  goto done
)
:done
echo the highest found is %filename%
exit /b 0
```